# $_POST variables are not set when validate a form with jQuery ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a html form and a jQuery function to validate my form.

When I send my form values to my php files, `$_POST` var is not set?

```
<form id="signup" class="dialog-form" action="bat/new_user.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="email@domain.com" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="My secret password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

PHP script is:

```
if (isset($_POST["mail"])) 
{
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    print $mail;}
    else{print "ko";
}
```

JS script is :

```
$( "#signup" ).submit(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
          var $form = $( this ), url = $form.attr( "action" );
         console.log($form.serialize() );
          var posting = $.post( url, { s: $form.serialize() } );
          posting.done(function( data ) {
            $( "#register-dialog" ).append( data );
          });
        });
```

How I can get the form values?

Comment: Try: `$_POST["s"]["mail"];` see your jquery code puts everything in object `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the data passed to `post()`, it should be

```
var posting = $.post(url, $form.serialize());
```

You are passing a parameter called `s` with value as the serialized form